# Cannot get the response in global variable

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

Hi i am new to vuejs and axios i wanted to get my axios and store the response in the variable and set that variable as global so that i can access it outside the code. However whenenver i console.log it always giving me undefined. Can anyone help me please? Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
async created() {
    let result;

    this.$store
      .dispatch('getAllProduct')
      .then((responseOne) => {
        // console.log("PRODUCT", responseOne.data.data)
        result = responseOne.data.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR USER RESPONSE ', error)
      })

    console.log('t', result)
  },
```

Comment: Please also post the related store action. At least provide a minimal and reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you added `async` to created you should `await` the response :

```
async created() {
    let result;
 try {
 const responseOne = await   this.$store.dispatch('getAllProduct')    
   result = responseOne.data.data
   }
   catch(error) {
        console.log('ERROR USER RESPONSE ', error)
   }
    console.log('t', result)
  },
```

if you don't want to use `async/await`, you should define `result` in data option and update in `then` callback :

```
data(){
  return{
    result:null
 }
},
watch:{
   result(newVal){ // watch the result property
     console.log(newVal)
  }
},
created() {
   

    this.$store
      .dispatch('getAllProduct')
      .then((responseOne) => {
        // console.log("PRODUCT", responseOne.data.data)
        this.result = responseOne.data.data
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('ERROR USER RESPONSE ', error)
      })

  },
```

Comment: you're welcome, you got this behavior because `console.log('t', result)` is executed before `then` callback which executed asynchronously

Comment: @TechDev It did? Hm, weird thing. Because apart from linting error (which doesn't affect workflows anyway), [it really isn't a must](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/require-await) for you to `await` stuff in `async` functions. I wonder what causes this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `await` in your code

```js
async created() {

  let result;
  
  try {
    let output = await   this.$store.dispatch('getAllProduct')    
        result = output.data.data
     }
    catch(error) {
        console.log('ERROR USER RESPONSE ', error)
    }
    
        console.log('t', result)
        
  },
```